# Error in query: column does not exist though there's the column in database table

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting an error as column doesn't exist by name 'createdat' though i'm querying as 'createdAt' which exist in my table.

I'm using postgres database

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', spaces.createdAt ) as start_of_week, sum(spaces.rent_amount) 
FROM spaces
GROUP BY date_trunc('week', spaces.createdAt )
ORDER BY date_trunc('week', spaces.createdAt )
```

> Error in query (7): ERROR: column spaces.createdat does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT date_trunc('week', spaces.createdAt ) as start_of_wee...
> HINT: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "spaces.createdAt".

Comment: Never user Uppercase, but if you do, change all your SQL statements and use double quotes " around the different names. In this case "createdAt"

Comment: This is what I'm running now -
SELECT date_trunc('week', "createdAt" ) as start_of_week, sum(rent_amount) 
FROM spaces
GROUP BY date_trunc('week', "createdAt" )
ORDER BY date_trunc('week', "createdAt" )